# When can a matrix be put in triangular form?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

Let's assume that we have an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ with entries in $\mathbb{R}$. I know that the theorem says that $A$ is triangulable if and only if its minimal polynomial $m_A(x)$ splits over $\mathbb{R}$. Do we actually need for the minimal polynomial to split over $\mathbb{R}$, or can we relax the condition on the statement to simply say that at least one of the eigenvalues of $A$ lives in $\mathbb{R}$? That is, if I start with $A$, which has one eigenvalue in $\mathbb{R}$ and corresponding eigenvector, can I construct a flag of $A$-invariant subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ + basis, which in this basis $A$ becomes triangular?

For example, can one put $A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ in triangular form? If not, where is the obstruction?

Sorry if this is not a good question, but I've been going through Hoffman and Kunze and I am a bit lost in the details surrounding Theorem 5 (and the proceeding lemma) in Section 6.4.

Answer (score 2):

No, you need all the eigenvalues to be real. After all, when you put $A$ in triangular form, the diagonal entries *must* be the eigenvalues (in some order). In particular, for your example, the obstruction is that the diagonal entries will have to be $1$, $i$, and $-i$.

Comment: Do you need all the eigenvalues to be real so that you are guaranteed to be able to construct linear conductor polynomials (and hence the flag of invariant subspaces)?

Comment: Right. What are you going to do with $f(x)=x^2+1$, as in the case of your example?

Comment: Ah okay. So, just to make sure that I understand, you need the eigenvalues to all be real. If not, then there is no way that you will be able to find a conductor polynomial that is linear for each step in constructing the flag. Hence, you will not be able to construct the flag of invariant subspaces. Is this correct?

Is there something that you can do if your minimal polynomial doesn't completely split?